# Java: My key isn't being adapted by KeyListener

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get my minigame, (paint) to detect keyboard clicks, I.e, Up arrow key to continue the line of an oval. The problem is that when I run the program and enter the up arrow key, or down or left or right, the program doesn't do anything. Please help.

Here's all the code:

```
package MiniGame;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameTest extends JFrame{
    int x;
    int y;


    //This class detects the keys pressed.
    public class Actionlistener extends KeyAdapter{
        public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
            int Listen = ke.getKeyCode();

            if(Listen == ke.VK_UP )  {y--;}
            if(Listen == ke.VK_LEFT) {x--;}
            if(Listen == ke.VK_DOWN) {y++;}
            if(Listen == ke.VK_RIGHT){x++;}
        }

        public void KeyReleased() {
            //There's no code here yet.
        }
    }


    //The constructor that initialises some components.
    public GameTest() {
        addKeyListener(new Actionlistener());
        setTitle("Game Test");
        setSize(750, 750);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        x = 150;
        y = 150;
    } //Paint method.

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        repaint();
    }

    //Creating an object
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GameTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener` for that purpose, use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Anyway, putting a `repaint()` in the `paint` method, will generate an endless recursion.

Comment: I think you added the listener to the wrong Component who isn't firing the key events. Try adding it the contentPane of JFrame. `getContentPane().addKeyListener(new ActionListener());`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a KeyListener! Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information why you should NOT use a KeyListener and working examples of `Key Bindings` to get you started.